# Why is my onLoad event for a RN video component not firing?

Tags: react-native, video, react-native-video

I'm trying to display an Alert message when the video is done loading, but this event doesn't seem to be firing; I've seen that other people have had similar issues, but I haven't been able to find a solution yet.

```
  <Video
    onLoad={() => Alert.alert("LOADING")}
    ref={video}
    style={styles.video}
    source={{
      uri: "www.myvideo.com",
    }}
    repeat
  />
```

Answer (score -2):

**onLoadedData** event does the trick:

```
  <Video
    onLoadedData={() => Alert.alert("LOADING")}
    ref={video}
    style={styles.video}
    source={{
      uri: "www.myvideo.com",
    }}
    repeat
  />
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by providing an example of the solution and how it helps the OP.

Comment: it was a simple answer to a simple question. 
onLoad event is not working. but onLoadedData event firing. so what do you want more?

Comment: The problem is it doesn't work either